# Angularfire2/Firebase - query with angularfire2 list subscribe on runtime not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am working on a project with angular2/firebase and using angularfire2 module. I want some realtime data so I use angularfire2 list and on component side using subscribe over the list. In real-time scenario, if any new item added in firebase database it subscribe but without any query. How I can archive subscribe with query? I am using following code where the query is some selection on which basis I want data.

```
getRealtimeData(query: any){
    if(query){
        return this.af.database.list(databaseName+"/messages", {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'is_broadcast',
                equalTo: query.value
            }
        });
    } else {
        return this.af.database.list(databaseName+"/messages", {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'timestamp'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am calling this in my component creating a query

```
      var query;
      if (this.isBroadcastMessage && this.isGroupChatMessage || !this.isBroadcastMessage && !this.isGroupChatMessage) {
          query = null;
      } else if (this.isBroadcastMessage && !this.isGroupChatMessage) {
          query = {
              value: true
          };
      } else if (!this.isBroadcastMessage && this.isGroupChatMessage) {
          query = {
              value: false
          };
      }
      this.firebaseService.getRealtimeData(query).subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log("data::", data);
      }, (error: any) => {
          console.log("error::", error);
      })
```

Comment: can you provide the Component code which use this `getRealtimeData` method? and also some logs of the object you receive?

Comment: Added in description, i want my subscribe get called with query. but it not getting called with query

Comment: weird, i tried this before, and its worked for me. the only difference is that i made the DB list query inside my component and not in the service.  you tried to do that?

Comment: Yes, but that will not make sense as subscribe always call without query :(

Answer (score 1):

User ReplaySubject

```
query$: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

First, create your `getRealtimeData` function like this like this

```
// you no need to pass any argument here
getRealtimeData():FirebaseListObservable<any>{
    return this.af.database.list(databaseName+"/messages", {
        query: this.query$
    });
```

then

```
public updateQuery(query: string): void {
  this.query$.next(query);
}
```

Now

```
 this.firebaseService.getRealtimeData().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log("data::", data);
  }, (error: any) => {
      console.log("error::", error);
  })
```

`subscribe` function will be called when ever you call

```
this.firebaseService.updateQuery({
            orderByChild: 'is_broadcast',
            equalTo: true // false
        });
// or
this.firebaseService.updateQuery({
            orderByChild: 'timestamp'
        });
```